# While running jobs on hadoop,got the following error

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I tried to run a map reduce job. Both my mapper code and reducer code (python codes)are working fine in my local system.But when i tried to run it on hadoop i am getting the following error

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 127
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:320)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:533)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:430)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:342)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1557)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)

15/01/22 23:32:06 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1414619043632_78083_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 127
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:320)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:533)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:430)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:342)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1557)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)

15/01/22 23:32:14 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1414619043632_78083_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 127
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:320)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:533)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:430)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:342)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1557)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)

15/01/22 23:32:14 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1414619043632_78083_m_000001_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 127
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:320)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:533)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:430)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:342)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1557)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)

15/01/22 23:32:21 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1414619043632_78083_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 127
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:320)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:533)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:430)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:342)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1557)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)

15/01/22 23:32:22 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1414619043632_78083_m_000001_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 127
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:320)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:533)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:430)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:342)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1557)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)

15/01/22 23:32:30 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
15/01/22 23:32:31 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1414619043632_78083 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1414619043632_78083_m_000001
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0

15/01/22 23:32:31 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 12
        Job Counters
                Failed map tasks=7
                Killed map tasks=1
                Launched map tasks=8
                Other local map tasks=8
                Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=51787
                Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
                Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=51787
                Total vcore-seconds taken by all map tasks=51787
                Total megabyte-seconds taken by all map tasks=450754048
        Map-Reduce Framework
                CPU time spent (ms)=0
                Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=0
                Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=0
15/01/22 23:32:31 ERROR streaming.StreamJob: Job not Successful!

Comment: could you please post or explain what you are attempting to ??

Comment: I'm trying to run MR job on cluster using 2 nodes.Hadoop accepts the job and change its status to "accepted" but after that it hangs there and then give the above error.Any idea?

Comment: If it's in Accepted state, the YARN UI will say why... For example, you don't have enough memory allocated for the job

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] of the python code, the input file, and the Hadoop Streaming command you ran. Also, I recommend starting with this http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/

Comment: Above issue has been resolved by vertical scaling of datanode instances,now able to run map reduce job successfully.Thanks!